# Give docker access to serial port

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, docker

Is it possible to give Docker access to a serial port? I am running Docker on a Raspberry Pi, that is containerizing a python application. My problem is that Docker has no access to the serial port. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Thanks in advance to all of those who reply.

Comment: Possibly answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24225647/docker-a-way-to-give-access-to-a-host-usb-or-serial-device

Answer (score 0):

The --device option lets you access devices within the container

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities